# Facebook javascript sdk asking for birthday permission randomly

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to get user_birthday and email along with some of the basic profile info for a facebook user.

I am not using XFBML in my view but an HTML button that calls the following javascript function on click

```
function loginToFacebook(){
     FB.login(function(response){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            checkLoginState('login');
        }, {scope: 'email,user_birthday'});
     return false;
}
```

The issue is a little strange, When I go to login and the permission dialog pops up. basic profile and email permission is always asked but user_birthday is random. for some id`s I can see this being asked for others not.

Am I missing something? any guidance? If you need other part of code, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> Apps requesting more than public_profile, email and the user_friends permission must be reviewed by Facebook before those permissions can be requested from people.

Meaning, `user_birthday` needs to get approved before it can be used by users, else it will only work for users with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester). There should be a very visible message telling you about that when you open the login dialog as Admin/Developer of the App.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Comment: Ahhh.. Yea.. I was able to access user_birthday from the Admin Id.. shey..stupid of me.  I know about the review process, but the birth date was coming for 1 id(admin) and not for others, So I assumed I am missing something. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: On the similar lines. I added a user as an admin to my application and requesting permission: 'manage_pages' , I do get the login box saying "some permission need review" but I am not being asked to grant the permission.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with user_email

While logging in a user has the choice to cherry pick their information sharing and logging into the application.

The best way to ensure data is captured accurately is to have an in-app form to ask them for what you need.